# Visual Effect window and a label

Tags: swift, macos

I can make all the window with a visual effect. But I cannot see the label when I apply the effect:

```
@IBOutlet weak var label1: NSTextField!

override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()

    let visualEffect = NSVisualEffectView()
    visualEffect.blendingMode = NSVisualEffectView.BlendingMode.behindWindow
    visualEffect.material = NSVisualEffectView.Material.dark
    view.window?.contentView = visualEffect

}
```

Here there is a very good solution:
[How to make a window with rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58940252/how-to-make-a-window-with-rounded-corners)

I tried to change my last line with that, but then the visual effect disappears:

```
view.addSubview(visualEffect, positioned: .below, relativeTo: label1)
```

How to have a visual effect in the window and be able to have also a label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On macOS `view.window` is `nil` in `viewDidLoad`. It isn't set until `viewWillAppear`. So this won't do anything:

```
view.window?.contentView = visualEffect
```

Add the visual effect in viewDidLoad and add layout:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let visualEffect = NSVisualEffectView()
    visualEffect.blendingMode = NSVisualEffectView.BlendingMode.behindWindow
    visualEffect.material = NSVisualEffectView.Material.dark
    view.addSubview(visualEffect, positioned: .below, relativeTo: label1)

    visualEffect.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    visualEffect.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    visualEffect.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    visualEffect.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    visualEffect.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

Does that work?

Comment: It does not work for me. I am in macOS Catalina. 10.15.1. Xcode 11.2.1. What is your version? Could it be a bug in Catalina?

Comment: Are you sure label1 is hooked up properly from storyboard? Does it display if you leave viewDidLoad blank?

Comment: I see the label but I do not see the visual effect. In any case, I have to put all the code in the viewDidLoad with a delay or in the viewWillAppear I have updated the question

Comment: Now it works! I see that it needs constraints before position but I am still confused about the differences between viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear in all this. Can you explain?

Comment: viewDidLoad: view is loaded from storyboard but not yet attached to a window. viewWillAppear: view is attached to a window and is about to appear. Hope that helps.